# jquery parseInt not giving the right result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am reading a value as

```
 var result = $("#Time", $(this)).val();
```

If I enter "Hours" instead of a number , and I do `0<parseInt(result, 10)<24)`, the result is true when I expect it to be false.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Note that (once you take David's advice, below) you may want `0 <=` rather than `0 <`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first comparison `0 < NaN` will yield `false`, which is sort of 0, therefore `0 < 24`, which is true.

```
var result = parseInt($('#Time', $(this)).val(), 10);
var between0and24 = 0 < result && result < 24
```

I also note that you seem to be passing context incorrectly. The context parameter to jQuery should be a DOM node, not a jQuery object, so use `$('#Time', this)`. Note that there's no use for that parameter in this code as accessing by ID is really quick as it is, and because you aren't using the `Time` id for more than one element in the document, right? Well you shouldn't.

Comment: How can I achieve the result to false?

Comment: @learning: By usign the code in my answer. changing from `x < y < z` to `x < y && y < z`.